# How to marshal C++ array to C# without specifying a buffer size?

Tags: c#, c++, arrays, marshalling

I have C++ function that provides an array to a C# method. I don't know how many elements I'll have in return. All I want is to pass an array (without specifying element count) to the C++ function and get it back filled.

My try so far:

C++ code

```
unsigned int lib_infos(
    const char *code,
    char **err,
    int err_len,
    char **linkinfo,
    unsigned int* linksCount);
```

C# code

```
[DllImport("mylib.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private static extern uint lib_infos(
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string code,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] StringBuilder err,
    int err_len,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray,SizeParamIndex=1)] string[] linkInfo,
    out uint linksCount);
```

Comment: I know this is somewhat offtopic, but you can pass data structures between c# and c++ with google protocol buffers with compile type checking on both sides and OO access.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly your question, you're looking to pass around an array without providing an initialized buffer. If that's so, I highly doubt this can be accomplished as arrays in .NET are immutable.

I currently don't have access to a Windows machine but I think you'll have to do something like this (please note the unsafe keyword):

```
[DllImport("mylib.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private unsafe static extern uint lib_infos(
    byte * code,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] StringBuilder err,
    int err_len,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray,SizeParamIndex=1)] string[] linkInfo,
    out uint linksCount);
```

Of course, this won't compile unless you add the /unsafe (or something similar) flag at compile time.

If I am right, I just got to say to you: "ve con dios".

With all that being said, you will still need to allocate memory in the unmanaged layer and then--for the sake of the final user--wrap the P/Invoke call to create an actual `string` to return.

Comment: I think you tried to say "vaya con Dios". Anyway, nice try. And nice answer. It looks like the OP want to make some kind of wrapper. It'll be useful for me too.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to do this. The C++ code cannot magically know the size of the array- or magically expand your array to match.

There must be a communication protocol for the array size- either you tell it the size of the array and ask for N items, effectively, or it tells you there are N items and then you provide an array of that size.

You cannot pass arrays back and forth without being able to determine it's size.

Comment: Sound reasonable. Can you give proper example how to marshal if i know items count, then?

Answer (score 0):

Add a sentinel value at the end. Then read the value(s) until the sentinel value and create the c# array afterwards properly sized.